# Analysis of lines in a point in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, intersection, line

I have 33 layers, 1 with points and 32 with lines. I want to extract/highlight the points where more than **one** line is intersecting. I have tried with buffers but I'm not getting anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by far not the best solution so hopefully others will post more efficient answers.

Take your buffer layer of your points and run the *Polygon-line intersection* tool from SAGA (I used this from the Processing Toolbox).

[image: Polygon-line intersection]

Your polygon buffers will now be split into segments depending on the number of lines which intersect it. So visually, you can see which "points" are intersected with more than one line.

[image: Intersection]

You can also see from the Attributes Table, which "point" is intersected with more than one line as it will consist of more than 2 attribute fields. If you have unique attributes for each "point" (such as `Name` in this example), you can always add filters for colouring or querying.

[image: Attributes Table]

Not an elegant solution...but I suppose it's better than nothing.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and sorry for the late feedback. It worked.

Comment: @Kasper, no need to apologise buddy! Glad it worked!

Answer (score 1):

You can do the intersection in the field calculator if you use the Well Known Text representation of the lines. The 'intersects' operator evaluates to integers 1 or 0 as true or false, so you could run that operation with all lines on each point like so (this example has two lines):

```
intersects(    buffer( $geometry, 0.01),  geomFromWKT( 'LINESTRING(-0.7023411371237458 0.00445930880713497, -1.01226309921962088 -0.2764771460423634)'  )) + 
intersects(   buffer($geometry,0.01),  geomFromWKT( 'LINESTRING(-0.9788182831661093 -0.00668896321070234, -0.75585284280936471 -0.26978818283166106))' ))
```

That will give you an integer attribute with the amount of intersecting lines for each point.

I don't know if there will be performance issues with testing a large amount of lines like this though.

When extracting the WKT from the line layers you can open the attribute table of each line layer one at a time and select the whole table, copy it, and paste it into a spreadsheet application. It should look like this:

```
wkt_geom                                                                                      some attribute
LINESTRING(-0.23615454012578607 0.16039895228401696, -0.322820561365618930.03445264803620229) text
```

Then delete every column except wkt_geom, and to a search and replace where you exchange ")" with

```
"))'  )) +"
```

and "L" with

```
"intersects(    buffer( $geometry, 0.01),  geomFromWKT( 'L"
```

and then assemble it all in the field calculator.

I tried this method just now and it worked as expected on a small number of points and lines. Again though, I don't know how well the method scales.